# Tabela dinâmica utilizando base de dados e Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, ui, shiny-server

Estou criando uma tabela dinâmica utilizando o shiny, porem tenho algumas dúvidas:

1° como faria para integrar o nome das colunas da minha base de dados num selectInput() para que somente as variáveis selecionadas apareçam na tabela e atualize automaticamente conforme eu selecione ou remova variáveis da caixa gerada pelo selectInput?

2° Tenhoum sliderInput() que eu gostaria que fosse utilizado como filtro de uma coluna, por exemplo, se o slider estivesse marcando o valor 100 seriam exibidos as linhas do dataframe onde essa determinada coluna somente apresentaria valores iguais ou menores que 100, é possível fazer essa ligação?

3° o renderDataTable me limita somente a 100 linhas exibidas no máximo, teria como remover essa limitação?

Estou aberto a modificações que possam fazer essa visualização ficar melhor

Segue meu código até o momento:

```
ui <- fluidPage( 

  titlePanel("EPE"),
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      #Todos os indicadores da tabela são selecionáveis
      selectInput('epe',"Escolha os indicadores", lista(EPE), multiple = TRUE),
      textOutput("resultado"),
      sliderInput('slider',"Intervalo",min = 0, max = 9000,value = 10) ),

    mainPanel(  
      h1('Tabela'),
      fluidRow( column( width = 4)),
      DT::dataTableOutput('tab') )       
 )
)

server <- function(input,output){

  #Testar o bom funcionamento do código por enquanto

  output$resultado <- renderText({paste(" ", input$epe)})

  output$tab <- DT::renderDataTable({EPE})   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo a primeira e terceira pergunta:

UI

```
                conditionalPanel(
                  'input.dataset === "EPE"',
                  checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Selecione as variáveis:",
                                     names(EPE), selected = names(EPE))),
                mainPanel(
                  tabsetPanel(
                    id = 'dataset',
                    tabPanel("EPE", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
                  ), width = 12
                ),
                dataTableOutput("EPEtable")
```

Server

```
    output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(EPE[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE], options = list(pageLength = -1))
    })
```

`options = list(pageLength = -1)` remove o limite de linhas.